# I want to send cypress test report after cypress run in the slack channel

Tags: cypress, integration, slack, mochawesome

I want to automatically send a cypress report after the `cypress run` is completed to the slack channel.

I don't know what to do, but I think there is a way to do that.

I have tried to integrate with cypress `Dashboard` but it will not send the `report.html` file to the slack channel.
`Dashboard` integration send only like this

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You can use slack api's to do that in the `after()` block. https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

Comment: Have you check the cypress docs? They have [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/dashboard/slack-integration#Install-the-Cypress-Slack-app)

Comment: @jjhelguero I have checked but don't want to run a cypress test with the dashboard. in that documentation when I run the test with dashboard it will only send a test overview like how many failed or pass. but I want to send `report.html` to slack.